# Como hago que mi aplicacion de laravel funcione en un servidor (Awardspace)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Actualmente tengo una app creada en laravel y dicha aplicación tiene un simple json en sus interior que al iniciar me lo retorna de una consulta.

Lo que pasa es que de manera local si me retorna un json y me lo muestra en el navegador ya que llego de la siguiente forma:

```
http://localhost/store/public/UserStore
```

Que viene siendo http://ServerName/CarpetaHtdocs/CarpetaInicio/Controlador

Cuando lo subo al servidor la ruta debería ser así

```
http://giblo.atwebpages.com/store/public/UserStore
```

Pero me sale el siguiente error:

```
https://www.awardspace.com/error-404/
```

Que vendría siendo el error 404 not found porque no haya la ruta que le indique pero no se porque si de forma local si me manda la respuesta.

Código de routes/web.php

Route::get('/UserStore', 'UserStoreController@index');

El código de arriba es la ruta que tengo agregada y si tengo ese controller y ese método.

Porque las `routes` no sirven cuando subo el proyecto a awardspace

Comment: ¿Es un servidor compartido o un vps o similar? ¿Es Apache, Nginx, otro?

Comment: @Shaz es un servidor de forma gratuita, tengo entendido que es compartido me dan pocas características por lo mismo y solo lo tengo para hacer pruebas. es un servidor apache con linux según las características que eh visto.

Comment: El servidor web (apache, nginx, etc) apunta, en general, a una carpeta "public_html" o similar, y tu necesitas que apunte a la carpeta "public" de Laravel. Si copias tu aplicación Laravel dentro del "public_html" no va a funcionar. Tienes que copiarla al mismo nivel que "public_html" y decirle al servidor que muestre "public". Busca una guia de instalar Laravel en un servidor compartido. Tiene su complejidad y tal vez no se puede hacer en este caso.